# How do I use Monodevelop with a GUI designer?

Tags: monodevelop

How am I able to use mono develop to make like a vb.net program not using the code but to where it has a window and you can add buttons and all of that.

Answer (score 5):

http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Stetic_GUI_Designer

You are going to use [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp)

Comment: Thank you so much!  And thanks for answering quickly to this now I can continue making programs using vb.net on ubuntu.

Comment: Also do you know why when I make a solution the project it makes comes up with the error project does not support .net framework 4.  I can fix it by deleting the project then making a new one in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the replies [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163878/monodevelop-netframework-4-client-profile-problem/166121#166121) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3818/vb-net-programming-in-ubuntu/281578#281578) should you be facing issues with .NETFramework4 on Monodevelop, I have been encountering the same error message the past few days on Monodevelop and the best I reckoned was switching from GTK#2.0 VB.NET onto GTK#2.0 C# and that seemingly addressed my woe, the other guys might have overcome the issue with VB.NET on .NETFramework4 I might have a look at it another time when I am familiar with Monodevelop itself..